# NFC on Android using JavaFX Ports

Tags: java, android, javafx, nfc, javafxports

I have been recently experimenting with [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/) and I have been trying to use it to build a native Android app. For the application I'm building I am trying to bake in NFC support but there doesn't seem to be much information out there about this. The only useful guide I found so far was some sample code written by [johanvos](https://bitbucket.org/johanvos/) on his BitBucket Repo [here](https://bitbucket.org/johanvos/androidnfcreader/src/c2f6ef73afaf8d1ad918cce3796d1886b1683276/src/main/java/org/lodgon/nfc/NexusReader.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

The problem I am facing now is using this code snippet, Netbeans keeps on reporting that the android libraries I'm trying to reference don't exist.

This is a some of my code:

```
package com.afropolymath.waitress;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import android.content.Context;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;

public class Waitress extends Application implements ReaderCallback {
    private Stage stage;
    private StackPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.initLayout();
        Context ctx = FXActivity.getInstance();
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(ctx);

        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(FXActivity.getInstance(), this, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A, Bundle.EMPTY);
    }

    public void initLayout() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (StackPane) loader.load();

            Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());

            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Waitress.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/icon.png")));

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {

    }
}
```

And these are the errors I'm getting:

```
/Users/chidieberennadi/NetBeansProjects/Waitress/src/main/java/com/afropolymath/waitress/Waitress.java:12: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
                      ^
/Users/chidieberennadi/NetBeansProjects/Waitress/src/main/java/com/afropolymath/waitress/Waitress.java:13: error: package android.nfc does not exist
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
                  ^
/Users/chidieberennadi/NetBeansProjects/Waitress/src/main/java/com/afropolymath/waitress/Waitress.java:14: error: package android.nfc.NfcAdapter does not exist
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback;
                             ^
/Users/chidieberennadi/NetBeansProjects/Waitress/src/main/java/com/afropolymath/waitress/Waitress.java:15: error: package android.nfc does not exist
import android.nfc.Tag;
                  ^
/Users/chidieberennadi/NetBeansProjects/Waitress/src/main/java/com/afropolymath/waitress/Waitress.java:16: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
                 ^
```

Any ideas on what might have been the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Johan Vos' NFC project works, it is based on the use of android and dalvik dependencies on the main package:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("${ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/android-21/android.jar")
    compile "org.javafxports:jfxdvk:8u60-b3"
}
```

But JavaFXPorts it's intended to create projects that can be deployed on different platforms, so now if you create a project using the Gluon's Plugin for NetBeans, you'll find four different folders to place the code:

- Source Packages [Java], for all the common code, shared with all the platforms
- Desktop/Java Packages, for Java code, only available running on Desktop
- Android/Java Packages, for Java or Android code, only available running on Android
- Ios/Java Packages, for Java code, only available running on iOS.

Also, if you check the project dependencies, you'll notice that the `android.jar` is available only for Android.

This means that you should create your regular project on the main package, and add the android part *only* in the Android package. In order to call the android class, you'll need to provide some mechanism on the main package to create an instance of it.

If you check the HelloPlatform [sample](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples), you'll notice that a `PlatformService` is used to load the classes depending on the platform, while `PlatformProvider` is an interface with the method/s that can be called from the main package, but will have the implementation given to each platform.

With this idea, but using `Class.forName()` instead of the service, Gluon [Charm-Down](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) library implements different native services.

You can have a look also at the GoNative [sample](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/samples) and [post](http://gluonhq.com/handling-android-native-activities-like-a-pro/) that explains it in detail.

In case you want to implement a new service, like the NFC for Android, 
these are the possible classes required.

**Main package**

*NFCPlatform*

```
public abstract class NFCPlatform {

    public abstract NFCService getNFCService();

}
```

*NFCService*

```
public interface NFCService {

    boolean isAvailable();

    boolean isEnabled();

    StringProperty tagIdProperty();

    // other methods

}
```

**Android Package**

*AndroidNFCPlatform*

```
public class AndroidNFCPlatform extends NFCPlatform {

    private AndroidNFCService nfcService;

    @Override
    public NFCService getNFCService() {
        if (nfcService == null) {
            nfcService = new AndroidNFCService();
        }
        return nfcService;
    }

}
```

*AndroidNFCService*

Your implementation of the NFC service. Here we can use Android API. NetBeans won't complain.

This is a minimal implementation:

```
public class AndroidNFCService implements NFCService, ReaderCallback {

    private final NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    private StringProperty tagId;

    public AndroidNFCService() {
        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) FXActivity.getInstance().getSystemService(FXActivity.NFC_SERVICE);
        nfcAdapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return nfcAdapter != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isAvailable() && nfcAdapter.isEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public StringProperty tagIdProperty() {
        if (tagId == null) {
            tagId = new SimpleStringProperty();
        }
        return tagId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> 
            tagIdProperty().set(new String(tag.getId())));
    }

}
```

Finally, you can use this service on your main class, once you get an instance of the `NFCPlatform`.

```
public static NFCPlatform getNFCPlatform() {
    try {
        if ("android".equals(System.getProperty("javafx.platform", "desktop"))) {
            return (NFCPlatform) Class.forName("<your package>.AndroidNFCPlatform").newInstance();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    NFCService nfcService = getNFCPlatform().getNFCService();

    if (nfcService != null) {
        System.out.println("Available: " + nfcService.isAvailable());

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey José Pereda, this is super helpful. Very detailed too. I am currently trying to implement this. I will let you know when it's working. Thanks.